# Meaning of "He has taken out a half-page advertisement in his local paper to put his point across."

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of **He has taken out a half-page advertisement in his local paper to put his point across.**

I understood like this
"He has taken half page in newspaper for advertisement".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To take out an advertisement" is a common idiom meaning to purchase an advertisement, so your understanding is correct.

This dictionary shows "take out" as a phrasal verb.

[Collins "take out" (2)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take-out)
"If you **take out** something such as a loan, a licence, or an insurance policy, you obtain it by fulfilling the conditions and paying the money that is necessary. "

The phrasal verb applies to advertisements (ads) as well.